# Unable to find view inside docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I'm using a containerized ASP.Net Core (2.1) app. The container is running Debian Stretch. Everything is working fine except this one small detail - whenever I want to use Rotativa I get this message:

```
Unable to find view '/app/wwwroot/templates/IssuedInvoice.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:\n/app/wwwroot/templates/IssuedInvoice.cshtml
```

That would very probably mean that file does not exist. Fair enough, I go into the docker container and issue `cat /app/wwwroot/templates/IssuedInvoice.cshtml` and what do I find? The file is listed without any errors.

Have anyone encountered such problem? I don't think that's a permission issue since the app runs inside the container as root anyway.

I have tested this outside of the container and everything works fine, same on Debug and Release configurations.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["JTEPanel.Api/JTEPanel.Api.csproj", "JTEPanel.Api/"]
COPY ["JTEPanel.Infrastructure/JTEPanel.Infrastructure.csproj", "JTEPanel.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["JTEPanel.SmsApi/JTEPanel.SmsApi.csproj", "JTEPanel.SmsApi/"]
COPY ["JTEPanel.Domain/JTEPanel.Domain.csproj", "JTEPanel.Domain/"]
COPY ["JTEPanel.Common/JTEPanel.Common.csproj", "JTEPanel.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "JTEPanel.Api/JTEPanel.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/JTEPanel.Api"
RUN dotnet build "JTEPanel.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "JTEPanel.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
VOLUME /app/wwwroot

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales libgdiplus wkhtmltopdf

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /app/wwwroot/Rotativa/wkhtmltopdf

RUN sed -i -e 's/# pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8

ENV LANG pl_PL.UTF-8

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "JTEPanel.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile?

Comment: @jpaugh sure, here: https://pastebin.com/raw/nN8nCxCm - I've tested with and without VOLUME, both versions don't work. Also I know that apt-get install is an antipattern, but I don't think that's the issue here

Comment: I can't find an issue, offhand. However, try replacing your entrypoint with `["cat", "/app/wwwroot/templates/IssuedInvoice.cshtml"]`. If it still fails, then it's a docker issue. (Maybe `VOLUME` and `FROM` interact poorly?) If it succeeds, it's a dotnet issue of some kind. (Maybe a missing system file?)

Comment: Or, is it failing before the volume command? `dotnet publish` might be trying to publish the cshtml files.

Comment: The dockerfile works fine by itself, but as you said, the file is missing after running the container with changed entrypoint - `cat: /app/wwwroot/templates/IssuedInvoice.cshtml: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment - I've fixed that issue by disabling View Compilation in .net app, but it only helped the `cat` command. The app itself still doesn't see the file

Comment: I wonder if you need a `VOLUME /app/wwwroot` mount after each FROM? I've never used FROM multiple times, so just a guess.

Comment: @drajvver Did you solve it ? Plz tell me I am having the same issue ;(